# hi i'm trying to read core libraries android.jar in android project is it possible.?

Tags: java, android

as i'm beginner to android trying to access core libraries from android.jar purpose to   access classes of android.view package present in jar file i tried with some code but it doesn't display classes a bit of error occurring..please check error logs.

```
public class TEST1 {
public static void main() {
    String packname = "android.view";
    String jarfile = "C:/Users/RAMA/Desktop/New folder/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar";
    JarFile jar = null;
    try {
        jar = new JarFile(jarfile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    java.util.Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries();
    while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
        java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enumEntries
                .nextElement();
        String nm = file.getName();
        nm = nm.replace('/', '.');
        try {
            if (nm.startsWith(packname)) {
                int stIndx = packname.length();
                String rem = nm.substring(stIndx + 1);
                int idx1 = rem.lastIndexOf('.');
                int idx2 = rem.lastIndexOf('.', idx1 - 1);
                if (rem.endsWith(".class") && idx2 == -1
                        && !rem.contains("$")) {
                    rem = rem.substring(0, rem.length() - 6);
                    String fName = packname + "." + rem;

                    ClassesDisplayActivity.your_array_list3.add(fName);

                     Log.i("Ramu","classname "+ fName.getClass().getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

}

error-logs

06-16 07:54:06.923:E/Trace(1700): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-16 17:09:51.925: E/Trace(1267): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-16 17:09:53.505: D/gralloc_goldfish(1267): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-16 17:10:31.555: E/Trace(1319): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-16 17:10:33.155: D/gralloc_goldfish(1319): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-16 17:10:40.924: D/dalvikvm(1319): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 8% free 2648K/2864K, paused 90ms, total 115ms
06-16 17:10:41.204: I/i'm in displayclass(1319): activity
06-16 17:10:41.326: W/System.err(1319): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 17:10:41.374: W/System.err(1319):     at com.api.testapp.TEST1.main(TEST1.java:18)
06-16 17:10:41.394: W/System.err(1319):     at com.api.testapp.ClassesDisplayActivity.onStart(ClassesDisplayActivity.java:76)
06-16 17:10:41.424: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
06-16 17:10:41.424: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
06-16 17:10:41.444: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
06-16 17:10:41.444: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-16 17:10:41.444: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-16 17:10:41.464: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-16 17:10:41.464: W/System.err(1319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 17:10:41.464: W/System.err(1319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-16 17:10:41.464: W/System.err(1319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-16 17:10:41.494: W/System.err(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 17:10:41.494: W/System.err(1319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-16 17:10:41.514: W/System.err(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-16 17:10:41.514: W/System.err(1319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-16 17:10:41.534: W/System.err(1319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 17:10:41.994: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

dos any one knows please solve this problem.

Comment: "a bit of error occurring" --> What is this error? You've got to be more specific.

Comment: 06-16 07:54:06.923: E/Trace(1700): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: Put that in your question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't see what this has to do with Android - that code definitely isn't standard Android code.

Comment: @Squonk i'm trying to accessing classes inside android.view package and it is standard code only.

Comment: The code won't work for a multitude of reasons. To start learning where it goes wrong, log your exceptions instead of ignoring them.

Comment: And no, its not standard android code. Android dont have a main entry point like this. public static void main() throws Exception {

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold u r right.but after removing throws Exception also it's with same error.s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the basics of Java and Android first. If you want to code for Android you cant access your local file directory of your windows pc. Anyway, there is no static main entrypoint for java. If you want to code for java, you can't use the androids library.

you should also dont ignore the Exception by letting the block empty.